# How do I programmatically check if a context is active?

Tags: 8

How do I see which contexts are active on the page?

I can't find any `ContextManager` object in `hook_preprocess_page()`.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out: The Context module defines a service for getting the `ContextManager` object, which has `getActiveContexts()`. You can obtain it using the following code.

```
$activeContexts = \Drupal::service('context.manager')->getActiveContexts();
```

I need to read [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet in template_preprocess_page():

```
  // Pass vars to page.html.twig depending on active contexts
  $active_contexts = \Drupal::service('context.manager')->getActiveContexts();

  $vars['is_my_context_active'] = FALSE;
  foreach ($active_contexts as $context) {
    if ($context->getName() == 'my_context') {
      $vars['is_my_context_active'] = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }
```